# Deleting posted content using $resource in AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs-resource

I am new to AngularJS and am trying out a few things with posting and deleting content using $resource. I've got the posting working fine, but when I try to delete something that I've posted I get a 404 error.

```
DELETE http://localhost:3000/tasks?__v=0&_id=53c5ddcf2978af0000ccdc50&beginningDat…vacy=true&title=This+is+a+complete+task&website=http:%2F%2Fwww.hotmail.com 404 (Not Found)
```

I've been working on this for a few days now and I'm just not seeing what i am missing. I am using a MEAN stack. I've got mongoose, express, bodyParser, and cors as dependencies in my app.js and created my endpoints:

```
app.get('/tasks', api.getTask);
app.post('/tasks', api.postTask);
app.delete('/tasks/:_id', api.deleteTask);
```

Here is the code from my api.js which

```
exports.deleteTask = function(req, res){

    var _id = req.params._id;

    Task.remove({_id:_id}, function(err, task){
        res.send(task + ' removed task successfully');
        if(err){
            res.send('Hey guys...he is still here.');
        }
    });
};
```

Here is my factory/service:

```
'use strict';
    angular.module('achievementApp').factory('tasks', function($resource){
        return $resource('http://localhost:3000/tasks/',{_id: '@_id'},{
        get: {method:'GET', isArray: true},
        add: {method:'POST'},
        delete: {method: 'DELETE'}
    });
});
```

And here is the code from the Ctrl:

```
$scope.taskList = tasks.get({});
$scope.removeTask = function(obj){
    tasks.delete(obj);
    var index = $scope.taskList.indexOf(obj);
    console.log(index);
    $scope.taskList.splice(index,1);
    console.log('removeTask was called');
};
```

Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. I've tried just about everything I can to get it to work and have had no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a mismatch between the angular code which is putting the _id in the query string and the express code which is looking for it as a route param, which looks in the path part of the URL. `req.params` comes from the path part before the `?`. `req.query` comes from the query string part after the `?`. It would be more conventional to use the path in terms of REST, so I suggest changing your angularjs code to have `/tasks/:_id` as the resource route.

Aside: Best to use relative paths in your browser JS and omit the protocol, host, and port. Otherwise your app won't work when you deploy it on the real web.